# How to define a writable integer as parameter in the kernel function?

Tags: metal

I tried to create a kernel with parameter

`device int &errorC [[ buffer(2) ]]`,

and set the buffer using

`[encoder setBytes:&count length:sizeof(int) atIndex: 2];`

But I receives error message saying that failed assertion `Compute Function: Bytes are being bound at index 2 to a shader argument with write access enabled.'`

Why? It seems that I should not use setBytes. But how can I set an integer and the kernel can write back to it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `-setBytes:...` method can only provide `constant` data, not writable `device` data. This method of providing data can be more efficient than providing a buffer of your own precisely because it may (behind the scenes) not use a writable buffer to hold the data.

Among other things, if you want the CPU to be able to read the value written to `errorC`, note that there's no way when you use `-setBytes:...`. There's no `-getBytes...` method.

If you want the data to be writable, you do need to provide a buffer using the `-setBuffer:offset:atIndex:` method.